# Scrapy: Can't select Content with Xpath, response.css in HTML Document

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

It's an odd one and I sit on this for nearly a week now.
Maybe it's obvious and im just not seeing things right anymore...
Any leads for alternative solutions are welcome, too.
I have no influence on the website.
I'm new to HTML.

I try to get specific Links from a website using scrapy. (how many is changing)
in this case RELATIVELINK1 and RELATIVELINK4; both are labeled "Details".
How many tables depends on how what you are allowd to see.

Before I start with the problem:
I'm using scrpy shell to test responses.
I get Values from all other parts of the HTML code.
I tried xpath, response.css und scrapy's LinkExtractor.
I tried ignoring the /p part in the path.

Now, If I try to get a response with xpath :

`response.xpath('/html/body').extract()` - I get a everything, including inside `<p>`
but when i get to
`response.xpath('/html/body/.../p').extract()` - I only get: `['<p>\n<br>\n</p>']`
and then
`response.xpath('/html/body/.../p/table').extract()` - I get `[ ]`
same for
`response.xpath('/html/body/.../p/br').extract()`

Here is the HTML segment I'm having trouble with:

```
<p>
    <BR>
      <TABLE  BORDER>
          <TR>
            <TD><b>NAME1</b></TD>
            <TD><b>NAME2</b></TD>
            <TD><b>NAME3</b></TD>
            <TD><b>NAME4</b></TD>
            <TD COLSPAN=3><b>Links</b></TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>
           <TD>NUMBER1</font></TD>
           <TD>LINK1    </font></TD>
           <TD>&nbsp</font></TD>
           <TD>NAME5&nbsp;</font></TD>
           <TD><a href=RELATIVELINK1>Details</a></TD>
           <TD><a href=RELATIVELINK2>LABEL1</TD>
           <TD><a href=RELATIVELINK3>LABEL2</TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>
           <TD>NUMBER2</font></TD>
           <TD>LINK2       </font></TD>
           <TD>&nbsp</font></TD>
           <TD>NAME5;</font></TD>
           <TD><a href=RELATIVELINK4>Details</a></TD>
           <TD><a href=RELATIVELINK5>LABEL1</TD>
           <TD><a href=RELATIVELINK6>LABEL2</TD>
         </TR>
       </TABLE>
     <BR>
```

There is no `</P>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for link_href in response.xpath('//a[.="Details"]/@href').extract():
    print(link_href)
```